# fire quick action from lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components

I've been scratching my head trying to find this solution with zero success. Can someone please help me understand if there's a way to call quick action from a component on record page, say on click of a button.

Answer (score 6):

[QuickAction Api is](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:quickActionAPI/documentation) not available in LWC yet.

You have to wrap an aura component around your LWC. Fire an event from LWC, aura component will capture it and then call quick action API.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/48.0/lwc/lwc.events_sending_to_aura_components

Comment: Hi Pranay, Do you know if QuickAction Api is still not available in LWC ?
Because I couldn't find anything about it.